# A module for each component or a module for all shared components?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this approach where I have my ionic pages, but these are made up of several shared components, my question is, should I have a single module for all my components in that "shared" folder, or that each component have its own module ? And if so, should I load those modules in a "shared module" with parent to child import?

Comment: Module per component. Only load the module if you **actually need** the component, to ensure light/quick loading. If multiple components/directives have to be used together (like multiple components for a datatable component), they should be in the same module however.

Comment: And pages should be generated using `ng g module register --module account --route register` ([lazy-loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend having a shared module for multiple components for no reason other than less 'clutter' and easy navigation of what's being imported and exported.

I tend to have one module per 'section' within my app and one module per directory.

```
/components  
    /component-one  
    /component-two  
    /component-three  
    components.module.ts  

/pages  
    /login-in  
        /login-in-component  
        /join-component  
        /join-success-component  
        login-in.module.ts  
    /home-component  
    /about-component  
    /another-component  
    pages.module.ts
```

This is a personal preference, however I find this approach the best.